# Getting pooled F-values and p-values for multiply imputed data in SPSS?

Tags: multiple-regression, spss, missing-data, multiple-imputation, pooling

When working with a dataset created via multiple imputation, SPSS pools some values but not others. For example, in multiple regression, I can get coefficients, t-tests for the coefficients, t-values and p-values for those t-tests. However, the ANOVA output testing model fit does not give me pooled data for the F-test and its p-value (nor pooled R2). What is the proper formula or procedure to calculate these values based on the information provided in the SPSS output?

Answer (score 1):

SPSS Statistics indeed does not provide pooled results for linear regression summary statistics such as the Model F test or the R<sup>2</sup> in current versions. For a pooled R<sup>2</sup> you could just average the R<sup>2</sup> values for the individual imputation results.

The *IBM SPSS Statistical Algorithms* manual chapter on Multiple Imputation: Pooling Algorthms gives formulas for combining quantities from imputed analyses to form F tests for linear combinations of parameter estimates.